# Remove dynamically registered events at a later point

Tags: javascript, dom-events, media-queries, addeventlistener, matchmedia

I have this code that registers an event to an array of breakpoints:

```
var breaks = ["(min-width: 800px)","(min-width: 300px)"];

var breakChange = function(mq) {
  console.log(mq);
}

for ( i = 0; i < breaks.length; i++ ) {  
  var mq = window.matchMedia(bG.breaks[i]);
  mq.addListener(breakChange);
}
```

It works great, but I want to be able to remove the listeners from these breaks at a later point. Does anyone know what would be the best way to go about removing event listeners registered dynamically at a later point?

Comment: `addListener` isn't native javascript, so we would have to know where that function comes from and what it does ?

Comment: @adeneo I didn't think so either, but [apparently it is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList#addListener())

Comment: Have you tried using the corresponding [`removeListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList#removeListener())?

Comment: @JamesThorpe - Good catch, and on the same page is the `removeListener` that does the opposite

Comment: I guess my question is more about the best method to go about using `removeListener` on dynamically registered events. Should I just loop through them again and use `removeListener` instead of `addListener`.

Comment: @user2522373 Pretty much, yes.  When you do so will depend on the logic you're trying to build.